# Error trying in conditional cases

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I created a query to show information in a range of months but is not working in some conditions.

Here is what i want

```
|jan| |feb| |mar| |apr| |may| |jun| |jul| |ago| |sep| |oct| |nov| |dic|
 id1   id1   id1   id1   id1   id1   id1   id1   id1   id1   id1   id1
 id2   id2   id2   id2   id2   id2   id2   id2   id2   id2   id2   id2
 id3   id3   id3   id3   _____________________________________________
 id4   id4   id4   id4   id4   _______________________________________ 
 _____________________   id5   id5   id5   id5   id5   _______________
```

And also this

```
|jan| |feb| |mar| |apr| |may| |jun| |jul| |ago| |sep| |oct| |nov| |dic|
  4     4     4     4     4     3     3     3     3     2     2     2
```

Here is my table

```
CREATE TABLE policies (
 id INT,
 date_ini DATE,
 date_end DATE,
 num_policy INT);

INSERT INTO policies VALUES
(   1,     '2013-01-16',   '2014-01-01',1234),      
(   2,     '2013-01-14',   '2014-02-06',5678),  
(   3,     '2012-03-17',   '2013-04-24',9123), 
(   4,     '2012-04-05',   '2013-05-24',4567),
(   5,     '2013-05-19',   '2014-06-20',8912);
```

Here is my query

```
SET @year := 2013;

SELECT
CASE WHEN CONCAT(@year, '-01-01') BETWEEN date_ini AND date_end THEN CONCAT('id', id) END Jan,
CASE WHEN CONCAT(@year, '-02-01') BETWEEN date_ini AND date_end THEN CONCAT('id', id) END Feb,
CASE WHEN CONCAT(@year, '-03-01') BETWEEN date_ini AND date_end THEN CONCAT('id', id) END Mar,
CASE WHEN CONCAT(@year, '-04-01') BETWEEN date_ini AND date_end THEN CONCAT('id', id) END Apr,
CASE WHEN CONCAT(@year, '-05-01') BETWEEN date_ini AND date_end THEN CONCAT('id', id) END May,
CASE WHEN CONCAT(@year, '-06-01') BETWEEN date_ini AND date_end THEN CONCAT('id', id) END Jun,
CASE WHEN CONCAT(@year, '-07-01') BETWEEN date_ini AND date_end THEN CONCAT('id', id) END Jul,
CASE WHEN CONCAT(@year, '-08-01') BETWEEN date_ini AND date_end THEN CONCAT('id', id) END Aug,
CASE WHEN CONCAT(@year, '-09-01') BETWEEN date_ini AND date_end THEN CONCAT('id', id) END Sep,
CASE WHEN CONCAT(@year, '-10-01') BETWEEN date_ini AND date_end THEN CONCAT('id', id) END Oct,
CASE WHEN CONCAT(@year, '-11-01') BETWEEN date_ini AND date_end THEN CONCAT('id', id) END Nov,
CASE WHEN CONCAT(@year, '-12-01') BETWEEN date_ini AND date_end THEN CONCAT('id', id) END `Dec`
FROM
  policies
WHERE
  date_end >= CONCAT(@year, '-01-01')
AND 
  date_ini <= CONCAT(@year, '-12-01')
```

Here is what i tried http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/699cb/1

Is not working in all cases and i'm having this

```
|jan| |feb| |mar| |apr| |may| |jun| |jul| |ago| |sep| |oct| |nov| |dic|
 ___   id1   id1   id1   id1   id1   id1   id1   id1   id1   id1   id1 => not working
 ___   id2   id2   id2   id2   id2   id2   id2   id2   id2   id2   id2 => not working
 id3   id3   id3   id3   _____________________________________________ => is  working 
 id4   id4   id4   id4   id4   _______________________________________ => is  working 
 ___________________________   id5   id5   id5   id5   _______________ => not working
```

Please somebody can help me with this?

I will really appreciate help.

Comment: Why isn't it working?  January-1-2013 is not between the the two dates so you wont get id1 for that first one.  Same with id2.

Comment: Can you check this please? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/699cb/1   ....It is correct

Comment: 2013-01-01 is not between '2013-01-16' and '2014-01-01' that is why it is null for id1 Jan.  And 2013-01-01 is not between '2013-01-14' and  '2014-02-06' for id2.  What am I missing?  It looks right

Comment: @Josh, I was writing that as an answer when I saw someone post a comment...

Comment: @CarlitosMorales, what do you want?

Comment: Can you help me please? i updated my question and added the final query

Comment: @CarlitosMorales, if you want to ask a new question, go and ask a new question, don't edit one you already have an answer to.  you gave Gordon the accept and then took it away from him too.

Comment: here you go http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/699cb/17

Comment: just made small fix, december wasn't working.  try now http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/699cb/17
There may be a more elegant way of doing it, but it works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to find overlaps at the granularity of month.  By using the `date` data type, though, you have to deal with those pesky days in the month.  As pointed out in the comments, January 1 is before any policies that start during that month.

The solution is to do the logic at the right level of granularity.  Use `date_format()` to format dates as YYYY-MM.  Then use the logic around that.  Here is an example for the first month:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN CONCAT(@year, '-01') BETWEEN date_format(date_ini, '%Y-%m') AND date_format(date_end, '%Y-%m')
             THEN CONCAT('id', id)
        END) Jan,
```

EDIT:

To get the sum, you would do:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN CONCAT(@year, '-01') BETWEEN date_format(date_ini, '%Y-%m') AND date_format(date_end, '%Y-%m')
             THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) Jan,
       . . .
FROM policies
WHERE date_end >= CONCAT(@year, '-01-01') AND date_ini <= CONCAT(@year, '-12-01');
```

Comment: It only will be working on january right? Do i need to added this to all months right?

Comment: @CarlitosMorales . . . Yes, you need to add it for all months.

Comment: can you help me please? i updated my question and added the final query

Answer (score 1):

Here is what is happening,

```
CASE WHEN CONCAT(@year, '-01-01') BETWEEN date_ini AND date_end THEN CONCAT('id', id) END Jan,
```

this statement is saying that when `2013-01-01 is between 2013-01-16 AND 2014-01-01` then select `Jan`  but the date isn't in between that date set

first day of the January is not between January 16th,2013 and January 1, 2014

Comment: Malachi can you help me please? i updated my question and added the final query